# How to make multi column List Box in ASP.Net?

Tags: html, asp.net, listbox

I want to make multi column list box in asp.net. At beginning it should be an empty. At runtime when user add some thing, it has to **add in list box in client side, not in server side**.

[image: I am exactly creating like this image.It's an windows application]

Now I made this [image: same]. Now I just want to make that filter list box with multi columns.

Comment: You should probably use a table for that purpose...

Comment: @user1429080 yes, I forget that option. thanks